# How to append options to an optgroup in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append some `<options>` to an `<optgroup>` using JavaScript. My optgroup is created if the `item.Level == 1`, then inside that group, I would like to include my 2nd level items as well. I am not great with JS, so if someone could shed some light, that would help out a lot.

```
 if (item.level == 1) {
     $("#chosen-select").append(
     $("<optgroup label='" + item.agencyName + "'>  " + item.agencyName +   ));
 } else if (item.level === 2) {
     $("#chosen-select").append(
         $("<option></option>")
             .text('\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0' + item.agencyName)
            .val(item.id)
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is basically to subselect the `<optgroup>` you are appending to:

```
} else if (item.level === 2) {
    $("#chosen-select > optgroup").append( // appending to the optgroup
        $("<option></option>")... // etc.
    );
} // <-- don't forget to close the else if here
```

P.S. You have syntax error on line 3 and unclosed `else if` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your loop looks like, but you could try something like this:

```
var $select = $('#chosen-select'),
    $optgroup;

for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    var item = items[i];

    if (item.level == 1) {
        $optgroup = $('<optgroup/>');
        $optgroup.attr('label', item.agencyName)
        $optgroup.appendTo($select);
    } else if (item.level == 2) {
        $optgroup.append(
            $('<option/>')
                .attr('value', item.id)
                .text('\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0' + item.agencyName);
        );
    }
}
```

This would store the last level 1 `<optgroup>` in a variable to be reused for all level 2 items. This would not work if there are any level 2 items before any level 1 item.